# Xamarin VS2019 Can not connect to mac building host via vpn

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have an issue connecting to a macmini as a xamarin building host over vpn. If I am connecting locally within the same network it works flawless.
However, when logging in remotley via vpn and pairing vs2019 with the mac the error message is 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'.

I have checked:

- Remote login to the mac works fine
- SSH connection to the mac via ssh 22 works fine
- Username and Password work fine

Is there any other port or anything else required to make the pairing work via a vpn?

Comment: Hi, if the segment of vpn is different from the local network, then it's impossible to make the pairing work via a vpn.

Comment: ok thx - the vpn segment is of course different from the local network (as it usually is accessing company networks). We will try to establish this then on a vm. Thx again.

Comment: Great, if not mind I will update this as an answer? Then other people who have the same problems will know the solution easily.

Comment: sure! thx Jiang.

Comment: Okey, I have updated it as an asnwer. Please remember to mark the answer when you have time , it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other port or anything else required to make the pairing work via a vpn?

**No**, because the vpn segment is of course different from the local network.

If you need to make the pairing work via a vpn, it will need to make them be in the same network.